# How to reduce the delay time even further in swift?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I have this code

```
let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 2 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
```

I want to reduce the time even further as 2 seems too long but when I put 1 its way to fast, how can I change it so I have more control over the time?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may delay any seconds as you like.For example 1.2s

```
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(1.2 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch_time_t` is `UInt64` time but the second parameter where you pass `2 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC)` takes a nanosecond. `NSEC_PER_SEC` it's a shortcut for 1_000_000_000. You can play with this value to achieve your desire time.

Example:

```
UInt64(1.5 * Float(NSEC_PER_SEC))
```

Answer (score 0):

NSEC_PER_SEC is just a defined value (1 billion) so you can get control by dividing it before multiplying. Best to stay in integer values rather than floats as should be more efficient and accurate. Given you know the value is a power of 10 you know that there is no precision lost in integer division by any power of 10 less than the number.

This example is 1,200 milliseconds:

```
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 1200 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC / 1000))
```

Equally you can just simplify and put in the number of nanoseconds that you want directly but it can be easier to read the number in seconds rather than nanoseconds.

```
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 1_200_000_000))
```